# How to create multiple route with laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using version 5.8 of laravel and I'm trying to initialize the routes. It is not possible to access the route created after the default route:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

I try to add a parameter in the second route:

```
Route::get('/page', ['as' => 'home', function (/page) {return view('page1') ;}]);
```

I got 404 error. How can I use multiple routes ?

This is my `web.php` file:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/page', function() { return view('page1'); })->name('home');
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Comment: `function (/page)` << Is this exactly what you have in your code or is it a typo?

Comment: You probably need to look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration#pretty-urls for rewrite conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Did you copied the second route, or what are you trying to do with this?

You can try this one instead as your syntax is wrong:

```
Route::get('/page', function() { return view('page1'); })->name('home');
```

-- EDIT

You can also return just the views from your routes if you don't plan to use a controller, like this:

```
Route::view('/', 'welcome');
Route::view('/page', 'page1');
```

Comment: I change it to your syntax but nothing has changed. But when I put it after the default route, I can be redirected to ``/page`` and the default route cannot be found.

Comment: Can you edit your question above and share the full content of your `web.php` file please.

Comment: I see your edit, but I don't understand what is your problem now. if you try to access it as `yoursite.test` it should load the `welcome` view and if you try `yoursite.test/page` should open the `page1.blade.php` file. Can you share the error that you get?

Comment: @navkov all right I tried this access ``http://localhost/laravelReview/public/page`` but I got te same error  ``404 Not Found``

Comment: without public it is: ``Not Found
The requested URL /laravelReview/page was not found on this server.``

Comment: @navkov  have I to import ``Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class`` in the ``web.php`` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196378/discussion-between-nakov-and-dakim236).